# making jquery for a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I'm working with Bootstrap 4 and navbars always need 2 clicks for open the dropdown menues so I want to manage it with jquery...

The navbar looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm" id="cssmenu">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#basicExampleNav"
      aria-controls="basicExampleNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="basicExampleNav">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="homeb.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="elements" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">Elements</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary pb-0" aria-labelledby="elements">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="element1.html">Element1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="element2.html">Element2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="element3.html">Element3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="options" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">Options</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary pb-0" aria-labelledby="options">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="option1.html">Option1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="otion2.html">Option2</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

And I m trying with something like this but I cant make it work...

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function() {
     $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function() {

});
```

And the problems are that, in the first part, it works but open all dropdowns, not only the one that I've clicked on it. And in the second part, I need to do the same $(".dropdown-menu").toggle(); I guess but again, only for the one I opened.

Someone please could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your markup works with one click without any additional javascript, perhaps there is something else on the page interfering with it?  https://codepen.io/pabbott/pen/oQporZ

Comment: You also didn't close `basicExampleNav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function() {

      $(this).parent().find(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the class to id:

This

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function() {
     $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
```

To This:

```
$("#specific_button_id").on("click", function() {
     $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
```

A class applied to all in the document where it mentioned and Id is for a specific task.

Hope you find it helpful. :)